# how to get html element id using javascript?

Tags: javascript, html

i am trying to alert the id of a div when clicking on an image inside it as code is:

```
<html>
<head>
    <style type="text/css">
        .test1{
            width:500px;
            background: #cc0000;
            color:#fff;
            height:200px;
            margin:0px auto;
        }
    </style>
    <script>

        function hidediv(){
            var a = document.getElementById("divtobehide");
            alert(a);
        }
    </script>
</head>
<body>

    <div id="divtobehide" class="test1">
        This is the div to be hiddenite
        <img src="index.jpg" id="imgid" onclick="hidediv()" style="float:right;"> 
    </div>
</body>
```

here the alert box appears but the id is not displayed. how to solve this?

Answer (score 6):

When you use `document.getElementById()` you already know the `id`.

You could even do this:

```
function hidediv()
{
  alert("divtobehide");
}
```

It doesn't make much sense the way you have written the code. Maybe there's a conceptual error (misunderstanding) on how `getElementById()` works?

If you want to manipulate a `DOM` object of which you already have the ID you can do this:

```
function hidediv(nodeId)
{
  var node;

  node = document.getElementById(nodeId);
  node.style.display = "none";
}
```

In the HTML specify the related id:

```
<img src="index.jpg" id="imgid" onclick="hidediv('divtohide')" style="float:right;">
```

This way you can reuse the function and criss-cross `<img>` and `<div>` nodes.

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
alert(document.getElementById("imgid").parentNode())
```

Answer (score 0):

OP is asking to get clicked element's div ID, not how to hide an element.
Once you get an element, you can use `dot notation` to access it's properties.
Here is how you do it:

```
var element = document.getElementById('id');
console.log(element.id);
```

Now, if you want an element's parent. It's a bit different. Pass the element itself as parameter of your function by adding "this" in between the parantheses.

```
<img src="index.jpg" id="imgid" onclick="hidediv(this)" />
```

Change the function header to allow the passing of the parameter. You can name it however you want althoug I suggest "sender".

```
function hidediv(sender){}
```

Now inside the function, you can get the sender's parent by using the dot notation `.parentNode`. This will make your function work, whatever image is clicked or whatever the div's id. Be wary tho this only gets the immediate parent of the sender.

Take a look at this: http://jsfiddle.net/TASmS/

Answer (score 0):

Here is simple solution.

```
function reply_click(clicked_id)
 {
    alert(clicked_id);
 }
onClick="reply_click(this.id)"
```

Comment: Hi, could you edit your answer and move the example code into a code block using markdown. Please indented example code correctly.